# How can I drag down a formula and leave some rows blank, but count sequentially the numbers?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a table with product details and I want to generate another table ready for Magento export.

It's hard to explain so please have a look at the table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s503gaqo1XV3PiJyr7HBkGago6YXiY4YesQVBETBbvY/edit?usp=sharing

I populate the data on the "Granit" page (I stripped 99% of the things as it's only an example) and I want to fill in the CSV page with the data from my Granit page. Go to the CSV page and have a look at column A  =Granit!J2 then I need to have 3 blank rows and the next one is =Granit!J3, 3 blank rows, =Granit!J4.. you get it. How can I achieve that? If I just drag it down I get weird numbers that are not sequential.

The next colum H on the csv page has another pattern I want to achive:

```
=Granit!K2 
=Granit!M2 
=Granit!L2 
=Granit!L2
```

I want to continue with

```
=Granit!K3 
=Granit!M3 
=Granit!L3 
=Granit!L3
=Granit!K4 
=Granit!M4 
=Granit!L4
=Granit!L4
```

(you get it)

Could you please help me? It would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to mimic **`K2 > M2 > L2 > L2`** patern delete everything in range **H2:H** and paste this into **H2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(Granit!H2:H<>""; 
 "♦"&Granit!K2:K&"♦"&Granit!M2:M&"♦"&Granit!L2:L&"♦"&Granit!L2:L; )
 ;;999^99); "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly. Could you help me with the A-Column as well?

Comment: sure. paste in A2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(Granit!H2:H<>""; "♠"&Granit!J2:J&"♠♣♠♣♠♣"; )
 ;;999^99); "♠")); "♣"; ))`